# smtp_error in when we test the email

Tags: error, smtp

can anyone help me to solve my problem "A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later." when we test email
plzzz help me as soon as possible
[image]

Comment: Can you please check system.log or exception.log? I think there is something in it.

Comment: sir i given the wrong username and password then error will be show that i have collect the info from mailgun than put in it that is working correctly